# How to solve "NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 161:" on the laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, routes, vuejs2, laravel-5.4

My routes is like this :

```
<?php
Route::get('manage-vue', 'VueItemController@manageVue');
Route::resource('vueitems','VueItemController');
```

Then, I access `http://localhost/blog/public/manage-vue`, there exist error :

> Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found. 1/1
>   NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 161:
>
> ```
> in RouteCollection.php line 161
> at RouteCollection->match(object(Request)) in Router.php line 533
> at Router->findRoute(object(Request)) in Router.php line 512
> at Router->dispatchToRoute(object(Request)) in Router.php line 498
> at Router->dispatch(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 174
> at Kernel->Illuminate\Foundation\Http\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 30
> at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in TransformsRequest.php line 30
> at TransformsRequest->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 148
> at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 53
> at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in TransformsRequest.php line 30
> at TransformsRequest->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 148
> at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 53
> at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in ValidatePostSize.php line 27
> at ValidatePostSize->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 148
> at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 53
> at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in CheckForMaintenanceMode.php line 46
> at CheckForMaintenanceMode->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 148
> at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 53
> at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 102
> at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in Kernel.php line 149
> at Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 116
> at Kernel->handle(object(Request)) in index.php line 53
> ```

How can I solve the error?

Comment: Laravel doesn't support not being in the document root out of the box, you'll probably need a custom `.htaccess` for that.

Comment: Try visiting `http://localhost/manage-vue`

Comment: In laravel you must have an entry point in routes file in order to work. So for your URL link `http://localhost/blog/public/manage-vue` you need this route: `Route::get('blog/public/manage-vue', 'VueItemController@manageVue');`

Comment: Would you please tell us what is your file/directory structure?
As I can see from information you've provided, there is a "blog" directory inside your server root, inside this directory you should have laravel files (.env, artisan, composer.json ...) and directories (app, bootstrap, config, database, public, resources, routes, storage, tests, vendor). Is it correct?

Answer (score 0):

I think your code is alright. You should check your webserver configuration though.

Check this out:

https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/

If you´re using Windows or Mac you could use very helpful tools, to get a fully configured webserver. On Windows it´s Laragon, on Mac take a look at Laravel Valet.